# ERC20 transaction not throwing error but balance is not registering

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ethers.js, hardhat

```
//abi not included here, provider is alchemy

const wallet = new ethers.Wallet(PRIVATE_KEY,provider);
tokenB = new ethers.Contract(
USDTaddress,
usdtabi,
    wallet
);
 await tokenB.transfer(account2.address,ethers.BigNumber.from(100),{gasLimit: 250000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'gwei')});

    let balanceUSDT = await tokenB.balanceOf(account2.address);
console.log(`Current account2 USDT balance:${balanceUSDT.toString()}`);
```

This code throws no errors but the USDT balance shows 0. This is on a hardhat local net with the contract instantiated already. Other functions including totalsupply work well. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you call the `transfer` function, the transaction is still pending to be mined by a miner, and hence until then, you will not see your balance increase. To fix this you can wait until the transaction is mined.

```
const tx = await tokenB.transfer(account2.address,ethers.BigNumber.from(100),{gasLimit: 250000, gasPrice: ethers.utils.parseUnits('100', 'gwei')});

await tx.wait(); // wait for tx to be mined

let balanceUSDT = await tokenB.balanceOf(account2.address);
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I did have this already:```  const receipt = await provider.waitForTransaction(tx.hash,3,0); ``` Which just times out.

Comment: Can you try not passing the third argument? `provider.waitForTransaction(tx.hash,3)`. The third argument is milliseconds for timeout error. If you pass 0, it will immediately trigger error.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that, but it still timed out regardless of the time, I even setup a mocharc file to change the timeout and that didn't work either. I'm currently trying to get the logs of the transaction, but if you have any other solutions, I'd be glad to try it out.

Comment: Can you just try once with `tx.wait()`, also you mention `mocharc` file, are you writing the code in test cases? Oh now I see, mocha's default 2 seconds is not enough. Can you post the exact error if you get any (earlier I thought you get timeout from ethers.js)

Comment: I solved the problem by restarting VScode. No kidding.